# .htaccess filepaths differing how to solve

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've made www.site.com/asd to redirect to www.site.com/index.php?page=asd. However, I would like to add one more thing, where www.site.com/products/asd would redirect to www.site.com/index.php?page=products&item=asd

I can't seem to get it working, I have this as my base code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(admin|pictures)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/pictures/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d



RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've tried adding:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&item=$2 [L]
```

in various locations of the .htaccess file, which either results in:
500 Internal Server Error
or
0 CSS files load in .com/products/asd And no pictures load in .com/anyfile

I understand it's path related, but is this a good way to go about it? Can I solve it somehow in the .htaccess file, or would I need to add some check that if it's product page and a product is shown, include ../css?

Answer (score 0):

The `^(.+)$` regular expression gives you a *"500 Internal Server Error"* because the redirection matches to the rule. So you gets the following error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)$ index.php?page=products&item=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+) index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So, the following URLs will be redirected to:

- `/products/asd` to `index.php?page=products&item=asd`
- `/asd` to `index.php?page=asc`

Answer (score 0):

Change the last two lines like this :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$  /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&item=$2 [L]
```

You should specify that in first rule a URI must come like `/whatever/` or `/whatever` so the second will match either `/whatever/whetever` or `/whatever/whatever/` and both will work individually  without any interference.